# TypeError: this.$E_0.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, modal-dialog

I am attempting to create a modal dialog in sharepoint 2010, but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: this.$E_0.getElementsByTagName is not a function
```

my code is:

```
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.html = '&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClass23FFBC76391C4EA5A86FC05D3D9A1904&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;RedConnect is now available.​&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;';
options.width = 700;
options.height = 700;
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

using firebug, i tried simply using the url field instead of the html field and it gave no error.

also related to this, what does SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions() actually do? what is the difference between using it and simply using a dict of values for your options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`options.html` requires a HTML DOM element instead of plain HTML code:

```
<script>

  function ShowDialog()
  {
    var htmlElement = document.createElement('p');

    var helloWorldNode = document.createTextNode('Hello world!');
    htmlElement.appendChild(helloWorldNode);

    var options = {
        html: htmlElement,
        autoSize:true,
        allowMaximize:true,
        title: 'Test dialog',
        showClose: true,
    };

    var dialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
  }

</script>

<a href="javascript:ShowDialog()">Boo</a>
```

Example code taken from the blog post [Rendering html in a SharePoint Dialog requires a DOM element and not a String](http://www.neilrichards.net/general/rendering-html-in-a-sharepoint-dialog-requires-a-dom-element-and-not-a-string).

> also related to this, what does SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions() actually do? what is the difference between using it and simply using a dict of values for your options

When you look at the definition of the `SP.UI.DialogOptions` "class" in the file *SP.UI.Dialog.debug.js* you see that its a empty javascript function.

```
SP.UI.DialogOptions = function() {}
SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions = function() {ULSTYE:;
    return new SP.UI.DialogOptions();
}
```

My guess is that it is there for client diagnostic purpose. Take a look at this SO question: [What does this Javascript code do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177001/what-does-this-javascript-code-do)

Comment: yeah... i figured it out a couple hours later and was going to post the answer but I hadn't enough rep yet :) thanks though for the answer to the $create_DialogOptions question