# Uses of colon in javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

1. Assign object literal properties `var foo = { bar : 'hello'};`
2. Ternary `var cats = happy ? "yes" : "no";`
3. Label a statement `outer_loop: for(i=0; i<3; i++)`
4. **What else?**

I'm poking through a sharepoint 2010 file and I keep running into this syntax

```
someFunction: ;
```

For instance, there is a file where the following function is declared near the top:

```
function ULSqvN() {
    var o = new Object;
    o.ULSTeamName = "SharePoint Portal Server";
    o.ULSFileName = "SocialData.js";
    return o;
}
```

and then later in the file we find the following

```
PageUrlNormalizer = function () {
    ULSqvN: ; //<---------------- This guy here --------------------------
    try {
        this._url = _normalizedPageUrlForSocialItem
    } catch (a) {
        this._url = ""
    }
};
```

**What is this doing?**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mJPT/) with full file. This same `ULSqvN: ;` occurs 47 times in the file.

**edit:** Added full code.

**PS:** Consensus seems to be that the sharepoint use of colon is "not actual javascript, possibly used as a marker for some external purpose". The browser sees it as a vestigial label and so causes no errors. Thanks for all the replies, I have left the actual uses at the top so that the question contains the appropriate answers. [question about same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177001/what-does-this-javascript-code-do/7543257#7543257)

Comment: Your jsFiddle link is just pointing to jsfiddle.com.

Comment: You point it out yourself: it's a label. It is likely automatically generated by the obfuscator (but I don't have a reason as for "why"). And, as always, the awful atrocity that is MS JS is showing it's ugly head... ever take a look at the Communicator stuff? :)

Comment: A label defined like that can't be used. It will be `undefined` after the semicolon: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/3F7UY/. The only other use I could think of is a tracing or debugging tool, or perhaps unit testing. Maybe the coder was using them as comments?!

Comment: @Sinetheta Would a *sane* programmer use "ULSqvN"? The SP stuff has a *bunch* of mangling (with even more cryptic names in places), so yes, there is likely a processing tool being applied.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff lol, thanks. Although that would be hilarious, it wouldn't be the saddest thing I've found baked into Sharepoint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has no purpose javascript-wise (since in javascript you would **only** label something that you can [continue or break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)), it might be used as a some kind of comment or marker for some parsing script. At worst it's just dead code with no purpose whatsoever.

Edit: looks like sharepoint uses it for some diagnostic information: [What does this Javascript code do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177001/what-does-this-javascript-code-do/7543257#7543257)

Comment: You win the check-mark unless someone can figure out a use for this code.

Comment: @Sinetheta I have clarified the "marker for some parsing script" part :D The point about being completely dead code for javascript itself still holds though

Comment: thanks for finding that question "What does this Javascript code do?" wasn't my first search when I went looking for answers ;)

Answer (score 3):

These are labels. Usually they are used to break out of several nested loops at once.

#### Example

```
function foo ()
{
    dance:
    for(var k = 0; k < 4; k++){
        for(var m = 0; m < 4; m++){
            if(m == 2){
                break dance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Credit: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564838/125816).

Comment: sorry, I should have included more code. Shouldn't a label immediately proceed a loop of some kind? Mine is just hanging out on its lonely, immediately followed by a semi-colon

Comment: @Sinetheta: yeah, that doesn't make sense. Maybe it's just abandoned code? :)

Comment: Wouldn't that function the same way if `dance:` had a semicolon after it? Maybe the coder of the OPs code didn't know any better.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Since this is a source file from sharepoint 2010 I'm really hoping it's valid useful js

Comment: @Sinetheta Wow, I was wrong. It's actually broken: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/3F7UY/. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label 'dance'`. After the semicolon it can't be used.

Answer (score 2):

It is am empty label, and then an empty statement.  (I can't see any good reason for this - unless there is something later in the function that wasn't included here, that needs the label to break out of a loop within that function.)

Comment: And the label name just happens to be the name of a function?

Comment: @Sinetheta - Yes.  This doesn't make any sense to me.  The script would execute the same both with and without the labels.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sounds like that is the consensus

Answer (score 1):

The third usage is to label a statement for use with a `break` or `continue` statement. See the [spec.](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.12)

Comment: thanks, forgot to include that. Still trying to figure out what's going on in this file though. It's straight from Sharepoint 2010 so I'm assuming it does something useful.